# how to force Make to take the "shortest path" from sources to targets?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this Makefile (it is just an example, does not make practical sense)

```
all: foobar.intermediate foobar.a

define RECIPE_THROUGH_INTERMEDIATE
    cp $< $@.intermediate
    mv $@.intermediate $@
endef 

define RECIPE_DIRECT
    cp $< $@
endef

%.a: %.c
    $(RECIPE_THROUGH_INTERMEDIATE)

%.a: %.intermediate
    $(RECIPE_DIRECT)

%.intermediate: %.c
    $(RECIPE_DIRECT)
```

I want Make to be as "fast" as possible and update like this:

```
>make foobar.a
```

execute recipe through intermediate, from `foobar.c` to `foobar.a`

but

```
>make
```

execute recipe direct from `foobar.c` to `foobar.intermediate`

execute recipe direct from `foobar.intermediate` to `foobar.a`

In other words, this is a common situation where to make a target (`foobar.a`) from source (`foobar.c`) requires internally going through an intermediate, and this takes more time, than going either from source to intermediate, or from intermediate to target, alone, but it takes less time than these two combined, when you explicitly (not internally) go through the intermediate.

Of course Make does not know how long the recipes take.

So I want to hint Make what the correct path to take:

- when I want just the target, take the direct recipe from source to target
- when I want both the target and intermediate, make intermediate and then the target from that.

I have GNU Make at least 3.82 but I cannot control the length of pattern stems - this has to work for any length stems, including, like in this example, where all stems are of the same length.

Is there a way to change the above Makefile to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I can see that people don't understand the question.  So I made it clearer, hopefully.

Comment: It sounds/looks like your makefile is doing exactly what you describe as wanting -- if you do `make foobar.a` it does the one-step recipe, and if you do `make all` (default target) it makes both `foobar.intermediate` and `foobar.a` (from that).  If you want `make all` to not build `foobar.intermediate`, take it out of the prerequisites for `all`...

Comment: @ChrisDodd no it does not, that's the whole point, as it is above, `make all` is inefficient.  The reason why I have the prerequisites of `all` is to precisely make the point.

Comment: Interesting question. How do you expect `make` to behave if `foobar.intermediate` exists (and is up-to-date) before you invoke `make`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are expecting doesn't  satisfy the Makefile rule,
If you have a closer look at your code then  you can observe following

```
all: foobar.b foobar.a

%.a: %.c                  // .a depends on .c
       from .c to .a

%.a: %.b                 // .a depends on .b
       from .b to .a

%.b: %.c                 // .b depends on .c
       from .c to .b
```

So .a here depends both on .b and .c .. since both .a and .b depends on .c and .a depends on .b the first rule `from .c to .a` is optimised by the make. and you get `from .c to .b` then `from .b to .a` there is no way that makefile finds the shortest path because all makefile wants to do is to makesure all the dependency criteria are met.

Comment: No, the pattern rules say: "we know how to make a .a from a .c: here is how". They do not assert that .a depends on .c. The dependency is introduced dynamically, when make searches the space of pattern rules to deduce prerequisites. It is reasonable that this could be optimized to take the available shortcuts.

Comment: This is similar to a jump threading optimization in a compiler. If you have a "goto x" where x is a label for "goto y", then the "goto x" can be rewritten to "goto y".

Comment: Yes I know Sagar, what you are saying I know.  My question was written very carefully - I spent time to write it so it is precise.  It says "change the above Makefile to achive...".

Comment: @Kaz. The go to example is understandable, but does makefile does any optimization before running? because there is a rule to be executed "from x to y". If there are no rules then I am sure make file will go for optimization.

Comment: I would say that the issue Mark is seeing is not so much a lack of optimization as an explicit "pessimization". There is no reason not to chase the graph in a breadth-first way which finds the shortest paths naturally. My statement about the goto jump threading was just a musing; I was reminded of it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior using GNU Make 3.81.

Obviously, that is not the real Makefile because it invokes a command `from` which does not exist. I changed it by commenting out the command with a `#`.
In my directory I have only the makefile, and a `foobar.c`.

```
$ make foobar.a
#from .c to .a

$ make foobar.b
#from .c to .b
```

Only if I comment out the `%.a : %.c` pattern rule do I get this:

```
$ make foobar.a
#from .c to .b
#from .b to .a
```

So there is something else going on. Maybe it's a regression in 3.82, or your actual makefile is triggering some bug, or maybe the short path is being chosen by fluke in my case.

It's clear that when you request `foobar.a` to be made, Make should search through its pattern rules to deduce a prerequisite from which `foobar.a` can be made. This should be a breadth-first search: it should encounter `%.a: %.c` among the pattern rules and see, aha, we have a `foobar.c` file, let's go! Only if this first round fails should the graph closure be extended to include prerequisites one step removed and so on. It's really even a question of clever optimization; just a question of the graph traversal order!

Comment: instead of commenting can you please check by putting echo? echo "from .c to .a" . If you put comment then rule field would be empty and make would go for optimization

Comment: @SagarSakre I initially tried it with a more full blown makefile which actually created the target objects. Still, same thing.

Comment: @SagarSakre The rule body is not empty with the comment because the hash mark is after a tab! So it is treated like a shell command (and you can see that the comment is printed as the rules evaluate, showing that the bodies is activated.) I think it's not much different from doing an echo.

Answer (score 0):

Having two different ways to build the same target [is explicitly not allowed in Gnu Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html):

> All the prerequisites mentioned in all the rules are merged into one
>   list of prerequisites for the target. If the target is older than any
>   prerequisite from any rule, the recipe is executed.
>
> There can only be one recipe to be executed for a file. If more than
>   one rule gives a recipe for the same file, make uses the last one
>   given and prints an error message.

The concept of multiple recipes to choose from, based on some arbitrary metric on the dependency graph, is unlikely to be supported.  So in order to answer the question you asked, Make would first need to be changed to support multiple alternatives in the first place.

If you want to supply a "hint" as to which of two strategies should be preferred, you'd probably have to use a conditional like `ifeq ... else ... endif` to define your desired behavior if the hint is provided, and the desired behavior if not.  By the time the dependency graph is built, there's only one recipe for the target.